# How to create a Mutable List of Alphabets in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a `MutableList` of alphabets form `A` to `Z` but so far I can only think of the following method as the shortest one without writing each and every alphabet.

```
fun main()
{
    var alphabets: MutableList<Char> = mutableListOf()

    for (a in 'A'..'Z')
    {
        alphabets.add(a)
    }
    print(alphabets)
}
```

So I wanted to know if there is any Lambda implementation or shorter method for the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `CharRange()` or using `..` operator to create a range.

For example:

```
val alphabets = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
print(alphabets)
// [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
```

or

```
 val alphabets = CharRange('A','Z').toMutableList()
 print(alphabets)
 // [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `('a'..'z').joinToString("")`.

```
val abc = ('a'..'z').joinToString("")
println(abc) //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

You can perform the same functions on a string in Kotlin as you can perform on a list of characters

For example:

```
for (i in abc) { println(i) }
```

This lists each alphabet individually on a new line just as it would if you converted it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rangeTo extension function as below

```
private val alphabets = ('A').rangeTo('Z').toMutableList()
println(alphabets)
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
```